# QGIS opening on background

Tags: qgis, windows-10

I have an issue with my QGIS 3 installation. For some reason, I can make the app be active over other opened windows (other apps or explorers). So, each time I need open QGIS, I need to hide/close all other windows/apps on top of QGIS. Any idea what causes that and how to fix that?

Here is a video that explains the issue with my QGIS installation - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CDkO1SIt09v0WWnASVZdGxvNylUec0KK/view (Russian voice)

Comment: I just checked and it works for me. For me it doesn't seem to be a QGIS error

Comment: It should resolve by simply logoff and login. I have faced an issue like this.

Comment: @KeshavSharma - the issue here is that I can't log out as many other long term operations are running on my PC right now. Is there a way to resolve this without need to logout?

Comment: Have you already solved this problem? I also have the same problem.

Comment: @ZsoltStegena - unfortunately, no. No solution yet.

Comment: I tried to 3.10, 12, 14, with all of them the same problem. Only the most stable 2.18 can work properly for me regarding this issue.

Comment: @ZsoltStegena - exactly the same situation on my end.

Comment: I've posted a bug here - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37827 let's see what feedback we will receive.

Comment: @ZsoltStegena - 3.0.0 does not have this issue. You can try https://qgis.org/downloads/